# Stolen iPhone 4 not synced with my PC: are my videos backed up?

Tags: icloud, backup

Last week my iPhone was stolen when on holiday in New York. I have precious photos and more importantly videos of my son on there.  I went to an Apple store in NYC and they advised that my photos would probably have been backed up on iCloud but he wasn't sure about videos as I hadn't synced my phone with my PC apart from when I first purchased it.

Is there any possible way I still have access to these videos?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your loss, but how could we know if you had synced your phone anywhere else like iCloud backup or backing up to a computer with iTunes? Do you want us to help edit the question to ask how you might [learn about iOS Backups](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946) or is there another question lurking here?

Answer (score 1):

If you did have iCloud backup enabled it should have backed up the camera roll by default. The camera roll includes both photos and videos taken on your device.

See support.apple.com/kb/HT4859 for more info about what is included in iCloud backups.

If there was no iCloud backup made, then it's unlikely that your data is recoverable since it was never synced with iTunes.